# Using common entity models from another microservice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, architecture, microservices, ef-core-2.1

We have to microservices.
How can we use an entity model from one microservice to another microservice without needing to maintain codes on both end?
The goal is to take the jsonData from a microservice and map it to entity model that exist in another microservice.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: You shouldn't do that, because that creates tight coupling between your microservices, which basically makes it a big monolithic application which is even harder to maintain than an monolithic application itself (since you get added complexity of Microservices) and you gain nothing from the microservices architecture, because changing one of the services and the datamodel requires you to change all the other microservices, build then, test then and deploy them **at the same time**. Completely voids the benefit of microservices

Comment: You shouldn't use microservices because its "cool", you should use then to benefit from being able to independently change, deploy or even completely replace one service while the rest remains untouched. That being said, you **should** have different models and DbContexts for each Microservice, which is exactly tied for what the Microservice does and a hand full of DTOs (also called ViewModels or Contracts) that you use for the communication between the microservices and map these back to entities.

Comment: Last but not least, please make sure to read the [Help: What questions are on-topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help center article, since your question is strictly off-topic (asks for opinions/best practices).

Comment: As i see it the question is do you create some 'Common model' dll. and have them both use it. or copy paste the class.
If it's just one class i usually prefer to copy paste it. for 2 reasons you might be forced to bring in other assemblies that data model uses. 
and you might take away the ability to do any fine 'twiking' of your currently shared class. 
what is faster and easier to maintain now. if the time comes when you have to maintain a large data model between multiple services. then have them share a common dll which contains only what is truly common between them

Answer (score 0):

You will need the assembly that contains the types you want to serialize/deserialize jsons. I think it is ok because when you have one service, you expect it to run autonomously, so, if you provide additional fields it should work (because it will not be affected by the deserialization). Now missing fields, the service will thrown exceptions and it is expected as part of the business.

One option, but not recommended (in my opinion), is to deserialize your json into `dynamic` and you will be able to navigate on the result as you want. I am not sure about the performance of this.